# In leaft.draw, using the event draw:deletestop, how can I get the specific layer that I want to delete

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

```
map.on('draw:deletestop',function(){
  //Here, I want to get the deleted layer
})
```

I used leaflet(v1.3.3) and leaflet.draw(v0.4.2)
May I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event-draw:deleted) you may achieve that using `draw:deleted` event.

In order to retrieve the specific layer you deleted you shall do the following:

```
map.on('draw:deleted', function (e) {
    // console.log(e.layers._layers);
    var deletedLayers = e.layers._layers;
    for (var layer in deletedLayers) {
       console.log(deletedLayers[layer]);
    }
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6k4arymt/

Comment: yeah，i see， tks